Distribution of probability and expectation
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find $\mathbb{E}(e^{\overline{X}})$, where $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ is the sample mean of $X_1,X_2, \dots X_n$, which are random variables that are independent and indentically distributed. I have no idea of what to do. I just need a hint to continue, only that, so I would be grateful if somebody could give me it.

Hint: try using the independence of the random variables? What does that allow you to do?

Do you have any more context? Are you studying the expected value as $n\to\infty$? In this case, I would try to use the central limit theorem. Do you know the expected value of $E[e^{X_i/n}]$?

Yes, indeed, I'm trying to find the expectation to use the theorem, but I don't know the expected value that you plugged in.

did you learn about moment generating functions?

A few observations that may help as hints:

$e^{A + B} = e^{A}\cdot e^B$
$\overline{X}$ is a sum of independent random variables
$\mathbb{E}[X \cdot Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent
If $f(x)$ is the distribution of $X_i$ (its density function), then $\mathbb{E}[e^{X_i / n}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x/n} f(x) dx$.

Note that if you want to calculate the expectation, you likely need to know the distribution of the random variables involved.

Thanks for your answer, I finally calculated it. The distribution was btw $X \sim U(-1,1)$
